# Not Printing DoubleArray as a table properly

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I am having tiny issue making these " ||" lines staying parallel to each other, can someone help me adjust the lines so the table is alined properly.

Thank you.

Main Class:

```
void printGui(const board_t* board)
{
    printf("Welcome to the Gui of the Game:\n");

    int i, j;
    char hash = '#';
    char x = 'X';

    for(i = 0; i < board->height; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < board->width; j++)
        {        
             if(board->gui[i][j].graphics == 'X')
            {
                printf(RED "| %c|" RESET, x);

            }

            else
            {

                printf(BLUE "| %c  |" RESET, board->gui[i][j].graphics );



            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
|   || A  || B  || C  || D  || E  |
| 1  || #  ||   ||   ||   ||   |
| 2  || #  ||   || #  || #  ||   |
| 3  || #  ||   ||   ||   ||   |
| 4  ||   || #  || #  || #  ||   |
```

UPDATED MAIN CLASS:

```
void printGui(const board_t* board)
{
    printf("Welcome to the Gui of the Game:\n");

    int i, j;
    char hash = '#';
    char x = 'X';

    for(i = 0; i < board->height; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < board->width; j++)
        {        


            if(board->gui[i][j].graphics == '\0')
            {
                //printf("\033[0;34m");
                printf(BLUE "| %c |" RESET, hash);
                //printf("\033[0m");
            }
            /*
            if(board->gui[i][j].graphics == x)
            {
                printf(RED "| %c |" RESET, x);

            }
            */

            else
            {

               printf(BLUE "| %c |" RESET, board->gui[i][j].graphics );

            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

UPDATED OUTPUT:

```
| # || A || B || C || D || E |
| 1 || # || # || # || # || # |
| 2 || # || # || # || # || # |
| 3 || # || # || # || # || # |
| 4 || # || # || # || # || # |
```

MY GOAL:

So after I did some major configuration^^^, it show the table properly but not with the function that I want.

So my goal is to when the user input a coordinates example 'B2', which will then change the spot into 'X' with a Red colour. But right now it doesnt change any colours so thats what I am stuck at.

X OUTPUT:

```
| # || A || B || C || D || E |
| 1 || # || # || # || # || # |
| 2 || # || X || # || # || # |
| 3 || # || # || # || # || # |
| 4 || # || # || # || # || # |
```

So this table is like a BatteShip game so there are ships hidden on the table which is display as '#' so the player dont know where the ships are and then when the user enter the coordinates example B2 it will display X because there is nothing there, but if I put A1 then it will display '0' because there is a ship there. So my point is to change the colour of the 'X' into red cause right now the board is all same colour even when the hit or not hit.

ANOTHER OUTPUT:

```
| # || A || B || C || D || E |
| 1 || 0 || X || # || # || # |
| 2 || # || # || 0 || # || # |
| 3 || 0 || X || # || # || # |
| 4 || # || # || # || # || # |
```

After editing the if statement with this:

```
if(board->gui[i][j].graphics == '0')
{
    printf(RED "| 0 |" RESET);
}
else
{
    printf(BLUE "| %c |" RESET, board->gui[i][j].graphics);
}
```

I end up getting up this OUTPUT:

```
|  || A || B || C || D || E |
| 1 || 0 ||  ||  ||  ||  |
| 2 || # ||  || # || # ||  |
| 3 || # ||  ||  ||  ||  |
| 4 ||  || # || # || # ||  |
```

The 0 becomes RED which is a good news but then other spots becomes blank and then the table become disoriented?Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In your output when you write `|   |` it is like the character is not printable because there are only the 3 spaces are you sure you initialized `board->gui[i][j].graphics` for all the values of *i,j* ?

You can use `isgraph` or `isprint` to detect non printable characters depending on you can have space or not  (`#include <ctype.h>` to have these functions)

Note also in

> ```
> printf(RED "| %c|" RESET, x);
> ```

there is a space before the char and none after, but in

> ```
> printf(BLUE "| %c  |" RESET, board->gui[i][j].graphics );
> ```

there is one space before the character then 2 after, to have the same column widths you need to have the same amount of spaces in all cases

Because *x* is always 'X' `printf(RED "| %c|" RESET, x);` can be `printf(RED "| X|" RESET);`

---

After your edit if the color must be red for '0' and blue for '#' and 'X', just do

```
if(board->gui[i][j].graphics == '0')
{
    printf(RED "| 0 |" RESET);
}
else
{
    printf(BLUE "| %c |" RESET, board->gui[i][j].graphics);
}
```

supposing `board->gui[i][j].graphics` values '0' or '#' or 'X'

Comment: I end up fixing the table but the colour is not changing for the symbol 'X'. Check my updated post

Comment: what character code do you have in `board->gui[2][2].graphics` ? It seems you have a # rather than the null character

Comment: I have 'X' on [2][2]. board->gui[Row][numColumn].graphics = 'X';

Comment: @Obamaself I don't think you have X because you write # in "UPDATED OUTPUT:"

Comment: @Obamaself if I well understand you need an additional information saying if the cell was selected or not by the user, you cannot do all just using `gui[i][j].graphics` except if you change its content

Comment: so, do you modify `gui[i][j].graphics` or not ? Note also '\0' is not '0'

Comment: can't I just do something like     if(board->gui[i][j].graphics == x)
            {
                printf(RED "| %c |" RESET, x);

            }

Comment: @Obamaself do you modify or not `gui[i][j].graphics` when a case was selected and depending there is or not a ship ?

Comment: I do modify the 'gui[i]ij].graphics, and yes when I do the 'if(board->gui[i][j].graphics == x)
            {
                printf(RED "| %c |" RESET, x);

            }' the X change into red But the table become messed up

Comment: I tried your solution and the colour of the hitted spot where the ship was there changed into '0' RED but the table become messed up. The table only show '#' on the places where the ships are and the other places that doesnt have ships is all blank, any idea why?

Comment: @Obamaself "other spots becomes blank?" that means the values in array are not 0 or # or X but may be also null. Sorry but I cannot continue to hope to guess for you, you need to say what is the initial value in each cells and what changes you do in the array and the associated conditions for

Comment: so basically I did a FIleIO of a file that contains all the details of the places that ships are going to be so right now, with your code, its showing the places of where all the ships are which is something that we dont want, So my idea is to fill up all the spots with # and then change it after when the user enter the coordinates. EDIT: I end up changing the colurs of the places that have been hit by the user where the ship was there to '0' GREEN  and the places that have been hit but no ships there into 'X' RED, but the graph is disoriented

Comment: Yes they are all saved in gui[i][j].graphics, Sorry for misunderstanding going on here, I am pretty nub when it comes to these stuff

Comment: @Obamaself so before the user starts the game what is the value when a cell is part of a ship and what is the value else ?

Comment: I end up solving the question with different approach aka different Gui. But thanks for your help, you brighten my views of the code